# how to use union in a loop I was trying to union the results thanks

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, union

how to use union in a loop I was trying to union the results thanks

```
DECLARE @STACODE INT;

SET @STACODE = 001

WHILE @STACODE <= 095

BEGIN   

    SELECT 

    DIVCODE,
    STACODE,
    EMPNO,
    LNAME +', '+ FNAME + ' '+MI EMPNAME,
    POLICYNO,
    EFFMM +'/'+EFFYY EFDATE,
    TERMM +'/'+TERYY TERDATE,
    DEDAMT
    FROM TBL_LISTING_NCR
    WHERE DIVCODE='089'
    AND STACODE= @STACODE

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
    'STATION TOTAL'DIVCODE,
    ' 'STACODE,
    ' ' EMPNO,
    ' ' EMPNAME,
    ' 'POLICYNO,
    ' ' EFDATE,
    ' ' TERDATE,
    SUM(DEDAMT)
    FROM TBL_LISTING_NCR
    WHERE DIVCODE='089'
    AND STACODE= @STACODE

    --UNION ALL


SET @STACODE = @STACODE + 1

END
```

Comment: You could just insert all the values into a temporary table in the loop and then select the data from that instead.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output

Comment: Which DBMS are you asking this for? Oracle? MySQL? PostgreSQL? SQL Server? ...

Comment: Microsft Sql server 2008 @thors

Comment: @nick can you give me some idea how to use temp table

Comment: @IanCabangunay it's easier to use Thorsten's answer...

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL we don't use loops like in a programming language where we must tell the machine how to do things. In SQL we tell the machine *what* data to select. In your case you want the rows for the codes 1 to 95 plus one row for the dedamt sum.

Here is a solution with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT 
  divcode,
  stacode,
  empno,
  lname + ', '+ fname + ' ' + mi AS empname,
  policyno,
  effmm + '/' + effyy AS efdate,
  termm + '/' + teryy AS terdate,
  dedamt
FROM tbl_listing_ncr
WHERE divcode = '089'
AND stacode BETWEEN 1 AND 95

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  'STATION TOTAL' AS divcode,
  ' ' AS stacode,
  ' ' AS empno,
  ' ' AS empname,
  ' ' AS policyno,
  ' ' AS efdate,
  ' ' AS terdate,
  SUM(dedamt) AS dedamt
FROM tbl_listing_ncr
WHERE divcode = '089'
AND stacode BETWEEN 1 AND 95

ORDER BY
  stacode,
  CASE WHEN divcode = 'STATION TOTAL' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END;
```

Comment: Msg 104, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION operator. @ thors

Comment: @ thors I want to make query where you select station from 001 to 095 and per station last row will be ded amt total per station. and so on per station

Comment: Okay, I've changed the `ORDER BY` clause so it gets sorted by station first. I don't really understand the error you are getting. The `ORDER BY` clause only refers to columns in the select list, namely `divcode` and `stacode`. Maybe the problem stems from non-matching datatypes. In the first query you select `stacode` which seems to be a numeric datatype. In the second you want it to be ' ', which is a string. So either convert the column to a string in the first query or don't use ' ' but null in the second query. I'd replace all ' ' by null.